# CloseFile command on printers doesn't print

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

I did a sample app with this code and it works for all printers - USB, network, and so on:

```
AssignPrn(lOutputFile);
Rewrite(lOutputFile);

for liIndex := 0 to lsLines.Count-1 do
    Writeln(lOutputFile, lsLines[liIndex]);

CloseFile(lOutputFile);
```

On `CloseFile(lOutputFile);` in the sample app, control goes into VCL files, and printing works.

When I integrated this code into the main application, on `CloseFile(lOutputFile)`, control goes into DevExpress files in a `dxPSPopupManKeyboardHook` method, and it's not printing.

Both apps are using the same IDE settings, and the `uses` clause is also the same.

Comment: You should add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to this q, especially as it apparently involves a 3rd party (Devex) library.  Until then, I'm voting to close it.

Comment: If the DevExpress unit is declared after the Delphi unit containing ``CloseFile``, than the DevExpress version is used! Write the Delphi unit name together with a dot before CloseFile to enforce the correct call.

Answer (score 4):

To select the correct function, use a fully qualified name:

```
AssignPrn(lOutputFile);
Rewrite(lOutputFile);

for liIndex := 0 to lsLines.Count-1 do
    Writeln(lOutputFile, lsLines[liIndex]);

System.CloseFile(lOutputFile);   // <===== FULLY QUALIFIED NAME
```

Comment: @poonam Can I insist that you mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem? And if it did not solve, please add a comment to explain why it didn't solved your problem. Good use of StackOverflow is the key to get good answers.